# Shortest code causing "Emergency stop." error

Tags: errors, tex-core

This question is purely academic. TeXing a file containing

```
\valign{\halign#\cr!
```

causes an `! Emergency stop.` error. Is that the shortest code which produces a fatal error in TeX?

Comment: You got me; I tried for ten minutes and couldn't find anything, so I'll upvote :)

Comment: most, if not all (haven't tested yet), answers here depend on the extensions of e-tex, which has been compiled into the tex engine of tex live for several years now.  this one doesn't -- it produces the same error message when processed with ` Version 3.14159 [PD VMS 3.6]`.  so here's the challenge: produce shorter code that results in `emergency stop` with knuth's *original* tex engine.  no prizes, just glory.  (and see my comments on the answers.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
\def\a{a\a}\a
```

**EDIT**: Shorter version, as suggested by Bruno:

```
\def~{~~}~
```

This gives `I can't go on meeting you like this`:

```
\halign{#&&#\cr\multispan{300}}
```

And this gives `This can't happen`:

```
\halign{#&&#\cr\multispan{300}\cr}
```

Comment: Good idea. That doesn't cause `Emergency stop.`, but `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=...].` And you can shorten that by 3 characters using the fact that `~` is active by default in TeX. I suspect that `This can't happen.` is harder to achieve :).

Comment: I was not very clear in my question, so it was a little bit tricky to decide which answer to accept. I am choosing this answer, because it is the only one that genuinely crashes TeX when run in `errorstopmode`. Other solutions go to `batchmode` (or `nonstopmode`) and can thus crash TeX much more easily (e.g., with an empty file).

Comment: @LevBishop -- congratulations!  this is the first "simple" code i've ever seen that reliably produces `This can't happen.`  unfortunately, it depends on extensions added by e-tex.  i'm still looking for an example that will reliably produce `This can't happen.` with knuth's unextended engine.  although such an example will probably not result in changes to the tex engine, it would definitely result in wider recognition and "glory" of a sort.

Comment: @LevBishop -- the code with `\a`, on an unextended tex, results in `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=327145]`,  and the code with the tildes results in `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=200]`.  (this has already been pointed out by Bruno Le Floch.)  both tested on `Version 3.14159 [PD VMS 3.6]`.  nice try, but i claim this isn't a valid winner.

Comment: @barbarabeeton are you sure that my `This can't happen` example requires e-tex? I see that the same code path is present in my "Computers & Typesetting/B: TeX:The Program" book (which describes version 3.14159), in section 798 (with the comment `{this can happen, but won't}`). I don't have `Version 3.14159 [PD VMS 3.6]` but with `Version 3.1415926 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)` which doesn't seem to understand e-tex primitives such as `\eTeXversion` it still gives `This can't happen`. I do agree that no changes to the TeX engine are required here, though :)

Comment: @LevBishop -- i'm investigating the possibility that i may be wrong about the current tex live tex being compiled with e-tex.  i have gone through the sources, tex.web, of 3.14159 and 3.1415926 looking for changes that may make a difference in this situation, but have seen nothing obvious (to me); i will confirm this with others knowledgeable about tex's innards.  the fact remains that the results when run here are different for the two versions, and i find that very baffling.

Comment: @LevBishop -- please send me an e-mail message (bnb at ams.org); i've tried to send one to you, but it has failed, and i need a good address for you.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I’ve stumbled on this question and I have two (not silly, I hope) remarks: 1) `\halign{&#\cr\multispan{300}\cr}` should be exactly the same as `\halign{#&&#\cr\multispan{300}\cr}`, and cuts down two characters ;-) and 2) I tried it on OzTeX 6.0, that runs on today’s Macs but still has `TeX, Version 3.14159`: it does *not* trigger `! This can't happen (256 spans).`, as it happens (!), instead, with TeXShop.

Answer (score 40):

A file just consisting of `^H` (IIRC the only character with catcode invalid by default in LaTeX) will do it:

```
[1 1016] ~/temp % echo -e '\b' | latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
**entering extended mode
! Text line contains an invalid character.
<*> ^^H

? 
! Emergency stop.
<*> ^^H

No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
[1 1017] ~/temp %
```

Comment: The hole-in-one of code golf. :-D

Comment: But why is `^H` the only such character?

Comment: @You: I'm not actually sure it is; but `^H` is the backspace character and if you find explicit backspace characters in your text file, something's wrong with your terminal and/od editor :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `^^?` and not `^^H`? That is, DELETE and not BACKSPACE.

Comment: Many characters are invalid in LaTeX (try `\newcount\foo\loop\message{\the\catcode\foo}\advance\foo1\iftrue\repeat`). I think the key reason why this crashes TeX is that somehow it is called in batch mode (e.g., putting an invalid character in a file and running TeX on it will simply prompt you for more material). Thus, `echo "" | latex` also crashes, with a different error message.

Comment: but this requires a response to the `?` prompt.  the original challenge was to create a tex file that stops all by itself, no intervention.

Answer (score 24):

```
{
```

Here's the log:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011) (format=tex 2011.8.28)  14 OCT 2011 11:17
**short
(./short.tex)
! Emergency stop.
<*> short

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

No pages of output.
```

If running with `-interaction=batchmode` is allowed then I win: just try

```
touch inexistent.tex
tex -interaction=batchmode inexistent
```

and you'll get

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011) (format=tex 2011.8.28)  14 OCT 2011 11:25
**inexistent.tex
(./inexistent.tex)
! Emergency stop.
<*> inexistent.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

No pages of output.
```

The output of the shell to check:

```
> ls -l inexistent.tex 
-rw-r--r--  1 enricomb  staff  0 Oct 14 11:25 inexistent.tex
```

Comment: I think your first example is also run in `batchmode`, because simply doing `tex short.tex` leaves me with TeX prompting me for more data. I think that `-interaction=batchmode` should be counted towards the number of characters :).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch The `{` example works also in `nonstopmode`. But you're right: skimming through "TeX, the program" tells that the only fatal errors in `errorstopmode` are of the "interwoven alignment" kind.

Comment: @egreg -- run with unextended tex, this hangs with a `*` prompt waiting for a response.  i'm not sure how to specify `\nonstopmode` on a vms installation except by putting the command in the tex file, but when that's done, it does result in `emergency stop.`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you still *use* a TeX on a VMS system? Sorry, but I can't test it, as my last experience on VMS was in 1993. :) Maybe `TEX /N` or something?

Comment: @egreg -- there are still a few "legacy" projects run on a vms system (e.g. annual reminders to members to update their membership information, uses tex because names and addresses contain accented letters, and the front end to the membership database is still on vms but probably not for more than another year), but book and journal production have been on unix/linux since about 2000.  (production systems change slowly.)  it's the only non-extended tex i have easily accessible, so took advantage of it for testing/wasting time.  i think e-tex was made the default in tex live in the mid-2000s

Comment: @barbarabeeton `tex -ini -jobname=not-e-latex latex.ltx`. Sometimes I create such a format for testing.

Comment: @egreg -- please send me an e-mail message (bnb at ams.org); i've been trying to send one to you, but it fails, so i need a better address.

Answer (score 14):

Another short way of making TeX blow up is to have a file named `+.tex` consisting of

```
\input+
```

Then `+.tex` inputs itself, and TeX sadly stops with the error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15].
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to crash the engine: `\closeout18\bye` causes a segmentation fault in pdfTeX and in XeTeX when trying to ship out the page.  The last line shown on the terminal is

```
[1zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  pdftex '\closeout18\bye'
```

Comment: I don't get any segmentation fault on my machine (TeX Live 2015, `x86_64-darwin`)

Comment: @egreg I still get a segfault with TeX Live 2015 `i386-linux` (I had tested that with TeX Live 2014).

Comment: Yes, I get it too with a Linux box (TL 2014), but it seems implementation dependent: a bug, rather than a feature.