# How to find error when the only error you are getting is an "Emergency Stop" in line 0?

Tags: errors

How does one go about finding the problem with a document when the only errors is "Emergency Stop" in line 0.  I have a rather long document and I fixed all of the other problems it told me to fix but this one persists.  Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) `:)` Please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can figure out what is going on.

Comment: Perhaps this might elude to some ideas: [Shortest code causing “Emergency stop.” error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31517/5764)

Comment: Did you recently update any files? Did you switch your compiler? What distribution are you using? Have you restarted your computer (sometimes, on Windows, an editor could have problems initializing things; at least I've found that with TXC)? Many questions.

Comment: I have restarted my computer and the doc is all equations like these $$f_{1}=\frac{2^{2m+2}-1}{3}$$ $$f_{n+1}=\frac{(f_{n})(2^{2m+(|(f_{n}\,\bmod\,3)-3|)\,\bmod\,3})-1}{3}$$ and a bunch of text.  I already read some other pages for help and nothing worked

Comment: I am using TeXMakerX

Comment: Please try to reduce your document, by commenting out parts, to a minimal complete version producing the error, and edit your question with this minimal version; it's even possible than in this process you find the cause of the error for yourself.

Comment: Forgot to end the document -_-
Thanks everyone for the help and i apologize for the anticlimactic answer!

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors"

erm. it just helped me...

Comment: @jheriko "**closed** as too localized" 12,905 views later... XD

Answer (score 6):

The way to find the error is to provide a minimal working example:

*reduce your document, by commenting out parts, to a minimal complete version producing the error*

It is quite possible that in this process you find the cause of the error for yourself.